# How to click the button and get the source of new page with python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I wish to click the `next` button till the end and scrape all the sources of the page. My code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common import exceptions  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('https://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E5%8F%A3%E7%BD%A9+%E9%9D%A2%E7%BA%B1')  
sources = []
for i in range(100):
    sources.append(browser.page_source)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.item.next > a.J_Ajax.num.icon-tag").click()
time.sleep(8)
browser.quit()
```

But all the sources are from the first page, when I have already wait for 8 seconds in each page and I see the images are finished loading. Could you please tell me what is the reason and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: your time.sleep() is outside of your for loop. Also can you see in your browser that pages are changed when click operation is performed ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the search results that are shown on the pages are AJAX and hence you will not be able to see them in the HTML source as AJAX is dynamic and stored only in memory.

You can access the data by finding the elements in the DOM, for example using CSS locators.